# how to specify environment in boto3 lambda create_function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

according to [the boto3 Lambda documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function), one of the parameters of create_function is `Environment`, a dict of string keys with string values. however, when I attempt to use this I get the error: `Unknown parameter in input: "Environment", must be one of: FunctionName, Runtime, Role, Handler, Code, Description, Timeout, MemorySize, Publish, VpcConfig`.

clearly the documentation is out of sync with the library. before I go digging into the code, does anybody here know the right way to specify the Lambda function runtime environment? [I'm using version 1.4.1, same as the documentation linked above.]

Answer (score 0):

it turns out I had had boto3 installed both as `pip install --user boto3` and `sudo pip install boto3`. right after posting my question I noticed in the pydoc that I was using the local version, which was older than the documentation. so I did `pip uninstall boto3` to use the newer version I had `sudo` installed. *but* I had forgotten to `pip uninstall botocore` to remove *that* local version, and thus my libraries were out of sync.

uninstalling botocore, so boto3 would use the one installed along with it, fixed the problem.

a good argument for *always* using virtualenv.